# Memory access violation after reading all objects from binary file and display them on the concole

Tags: c++, file-io, binaryfiles

I have a class `Tort`(representation of the cake), in the `main()` in the `switch` statement I call the function `displayAllTorts()` which should read the objects of Tort from the file (objects were written to the file upfront) and display them on the console. In the `displayAllTorts()` function, I create a `Tort` instance variable, read from the file to it, and then print it. However, after looping ends and for block ends, the destructor is called and an Exception - Memory access violation is thrown.

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
enum {
    choice_Quit,
    choice_InitializeCake,
    choice_PrintCake,
    choice_SaveToFile,
    choice_InitializeFromFile,
    choice_CompareCakes,
    choice_SortingCakes,
    choice_SortingCakesFromFile,
    choice_DisplayAllTortsFromFile,
};

class Tort
{
private:
    static int countObj;
    int count_parts;
    string cream;
protected:
    string congratulation;
public:
    string name;
    Tort();
    Tort(string, string, string, int);
    Tort(const Tort&);
    ~Tort();

    void setName(string);
    void setCream(string);
    void setCongr(string);
    void setCountParts(int);

    string getName();
    string getCream();
    string getCongr();
    int getCountParts();

    void printTort(string);
    void dataToInstance();
    int writeInstance(string);
    int setInstance(string, int);
    void cut(int);
    void cut();
    static int getCountInst();


    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Tort& t);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Tort& t);

    friend ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& ofs, const Tort& t);
    friend ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& ifs, Tort& t);

    bool operator<(const Tort& t);
    bool operator>(const Tort& t);
    bool operator==(const Tort& t);
    

};

int divide(vector<Tort>&cakes, int start, int end);
void Quick(vector<Tort>& cakes, int start, int end);
void printVector(const vector<Tort>& v);
bool FileExists(string filename);
int enter_number(const string);
int menu();
int getValidIndex(const vector<Tort>& cakes);
int read_cakes_from_file(vector<Tort>& cakes, string filename);
void displayAllTorts(string file_name);

int main()
{
    string f_name = "file.dat"; string f_name1 = "file1.dat";
    if (FileExists(f_name)) {
        const char* c_f_name = f_name.c_str();
        remove(c_f_name);
    }
    vector<Tort> cakes;
    cout << "Number of torts are " << Tort::getCountInst() << endl;
    int choice;
    while ((choice = menu()) != choice_Quit) {
        switch (choice) {
        case choice_InitializeCake:
        {
            Tort cake = Tort();
            cin >> cake;
            cakes.push_back(cake);

            break;

        }
        case choice_PrintCake:
        {
            if (cakes.empty()) {
                cout << "\nNo cake instances available!\n";

                break;
            }

            int index = getValidIndex(cakes);

            cout << cakes[index];

            break;
        }
        case choice_SaveToFile:
        {
            if (cakes.empty()) {
                cout << "\nNo cake instances available!\n";

                break;
            }

            int index = getValidIndex(cakes);

            if (cakes[index].writeInstance(f_name))
                cout << "\nCake instance saved to file!\n";

            break;
        }
        case choice_InitializeFromFile:
        {
            if (cakes.empty()) {
                cout << "\nNo cake instances available!\n";

                break;
            }

            int index = getValidIndex(cakes);

            Tort cake ;

            cake.setInstance(f_name, index);
            cout << "\nThe cake is initialized from file...";
            cakes.push_back(cake);

            break;
        }
        case choice_CompareCakes:
        {

            Tort cake1 = Tort("Chocolate", "Happy birthday", "no cream", 6);
            cake1.printTort("1");
            Tort cake2 = Tort("Chocolate", "Happy birthday", "no cream", 6);
            cake1.printTort("1");

            cout << boolalpha << "\nCake1 is equal to cake2 ?  " << (cake1 == cake2) << endl;

            Tort cake3 = Tort("Tiramisu", "Happy Wedding Day!", "no cream", 3);
            cake3.printTort("3");

            Tort cake4 = Tort("Napoleon", "Happy Mother's Day!", "no cream", 7);
            cake4.printTort("4");

            if (cake3 > cake4) {

                cout << endl << cake3.name << " cake has more parts than " << cake4.name << " cake." << endl;

            }else if (cake3 < cake4) {

                cout << endl << cake3.name << " cake has less parts than " << cake4.name << " cake." << endl;

            }else if (cake3 == cake4) {
                cout << endl << cake3.name << " cake has the same number of parts as " << cake4.name << " cake." << endl;
            }

            break;
        }

        case choice_SortingCakes:
        {
            if (cakes.empty()) {
                cout << "\nNo cake instances available!\n";

                break;
            }

            cout << "\nVECTOR BEFORE SORTING\n";
            printVector(cakes);

            Quick(cakes, 0, cakes.size() - 1);

            cout << "\nVECTOR AFTER SORTING\n";
            printVector(cakes);

            break;
        }

        case choice_SortingCakesFromFile:
        {
            vector<Tort> cakes1;

            if (read_cakes_from_file(cakes1, f_name1)) {
                cout<< "\nCakes saved from file to vector\n";
            }

            cout << "\nVECTOR BEFORE SORTING\n";
            printVector(cakes1);

            Quick(cakes1, 0, cakes1.size() - 1);

            cout << "\nVECTOR AFTER SORTING\n";
            printVector(cakes1);

            break;


        }
        case choice_DisplayAllTortsFromFile:
        {
            displayAllTorts(f_name1);
            break;
        }


        default: cout << "\nIncorrect choice.\n";
            break;
        }

        

    }

    cout << "\nExiting...\n";
    puts("End of Program!");


    return 0;
}

int Tort::countObj = 0;
Tort::Tort()
{
    count_parts = 1;
    name = "Chocolate Tort";
    congratulation = "Congratulations!";
    cream = "chocolate";
   // cout << "\nDefault constructor...\n";
    countObj++;
   // cout << "\nNumber of torts: " << getCountInst() << endl;
}

Tort::Tort(string name, string congratulation, string cream, int count1)
{
    count_parts = count1;
    this->name = name;
    this->congratulation = congratulation;
    this->cream = cream;
    //cout << "\nConstructor with parameters...\n";
    countObj++;
    //cout << "\nNumber of torts: " << getCountInst() << endl;
}

Tort::Tort(const Tort& A)
{
    count_parts = A.count_parts;
    name = A.name;
    congratulation = A.congratulation;
    cream = A.cream;
   // cout << "\nCopy constructor...\n";
    countObj++;
    //cout << "\nNumber of torts: " << getCountInst() << endl;
}

Tort::~Tort()
{
    //cout << "\nDestructor...\n";
    countObj--;
    //cout << "\nNumber of torts: " << getCountInst() << endl;
}

void Tort::setName(string name)
{
    this->name = name;
}

void Tort::setCream(string cream1)
{
    cream = cream1;
}

void Tort::setCongr(string congratulation)
{
    this->congratulation = congratulation;
}

void Tort::setCountParts(int count_parts)
{
    this->count_parts = count_parts;
}

string Tort::getName()
{
    return name;
}

string Tort::getCongr()
{
    return congratulation;
}

string Tort::getCream()
{
    return cream;
}

int Tort::getCountParts()
{
    return count_parts;
}

void Tort::printTort(string msg) 
{
    cout << "\nCake " << msg << endl
        << setw(10) << "Name: " << setw(15) << name
        << setw(10) << "| Number of parts: " << setw(3) << count_parts
        << setw(10) << "| Cream: " << setw(5) << cream
        << setw(10) << "| Congratulations: " << setw(5) << congratulation << endl;
}



void Tort::dataToInstance()
{
    cout << "\nEnter name: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Enter congratulation: ";
    getline(cin, congratulation);
    count_parts = enter_number("number of parts");
    cout << "Enter cream: ";
    getline(cin, cream);
}



int Tort::writeInstance(string file_name) 
{
    ofstream f(file_name, ios_base::binary | ios_base::app);
    if (!f)
    {
        cout << "\nFile " << file_name << " is not found!";
        return 0;
    }

    f << *this;
    f.close();
    return 1;
}


int Tort::setInstance(string file_name, int position) 
{
    ifstream f(file_name, ios_base::binary);
    if (!f)
    {
        cout << "\nFile " << file_name << " is not found!";
        return 0;
    }

    f.seekg(position * sizeof(Tort));
    f >> *this;

    return 1;

}


void Tort::cut(int num) { 
    if (num <= 1) { cout << "\nThe Tort can't be cutted."; return; }

    count_parts += num;
    cout << "Cutting the Tort into " << count_parts << " parts." << endl;

}

void Tort::cut() { // зменшення кількості частин
    if (count_parts == 0) cout << "\nThe Tort has already been eaten.";
    else {
        count_parts--;
        cout << "\nThe Tort is cutted\n";
    }
}

int Tort::getCountInst() 
{
    return countObj;
}

int menu() {
    cout << "\n===========MENU===========\n\n" <<
        choice_Quit << " - EXIT\n\n" <<
        choice_InitializeCake << " - INITIALIZE THE CAKE\n" <<
        choice_PrintCake << " - PRINT CAKE\n" <<
        choice_SaveToFile << " - SAVE CAKE TO FILE\n" <<
        choice_InitializeFromFile << " - INITIALIZE CAKE FROM FILE\n" <<
        choice_CompareCakes << " - COMPARE CAKES\n" <<
        choice_SortingCakes << " - SORTING THE CAKES\n" <<
        choice_SortingCakesFromFile << " - SORTING CAKES FROM FILE\n" <<
        choice_DisplayAllTortsFromFile << " - ShowFILE\n";
       
    return enter_number("your choice");
}


int enter_number(const string msg)
{
    cout << "Enter " << msg << ": ";
    string res;
    getline(cin, res);
    try {
        return stoi(res);
    }
    catch (const exception& e) {
        cout << "Error: Invalid input. Please enter a numeric value." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}

int getValidIndex(const vector<Tort>& cakes) { 
    int number;
    do {
        cout << "\nEnter the number of the cake to select (1-" << cakes.size() << "): ";
        cin >> number;
        cin.ignore();
    } while (number < 1 || number > cakes.size());
    return number - 1;
}

bool FileExists(string filename)
{
    ifstream file(filename);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        return 1;
        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}


istream& operator>>(istream& is, Tort& t) {

    cout << "\nEnter name: ";
    getline(is, t.name);
    cout << "Enter congratulation: ";
    getline(is, t.congratulation);
    cout << "Enter cream: ";
    getline(is, t.cream);
    t.count_parts = enter_number("number of parts");
    return is;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Tort& t)
{
    os << "\nCake " << endl
        << setw(10) << "Name: " << setw(5) << t.name
        << setw(10) << "| Number of parts: " << setw(3) << t.count_parts
        << setw(10) << "| Cream: " << setw(5) << t.cream
        << setw(10) << "| Congratulations: " << setw(5) << t.congratulation << endl;

    return os;
}

ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& ofs, const Tort& t)
{
    ofs.write((char*)&t, sizeof(Tort));
    return ofs;
}

ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& ifs, Tort& t)
{
    ifs.read((char*)&t, sizeof(Tort));
    return ifs;
}



 bool Tort:: operator<(const Tort& t) {
     return count_parts < t.count_parts;
 }

 bool Tort :: operator>(const Tort& t) {
     return count_parts > t.count_parts;
 }

 bool Tort :: operator ==(const Tort& t) {
     return count_parts == t.count_parts && name == t.name && cream == t.cream && congratulation == t.congratulation;
 }


 void printVector(const vector<Tort>& v) {
     for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
         cout << "Tort #" << i + 1 << ":" << endl;
         cout << v[i] << endl;
     }
 }


 int divide(vector<Tort>& cakes, int start, int end)
 {
     int i = start;
     int j = end;
     Tort pivot = cakes[(start + end) / 2];

     while (i <= j) {
         while (cakes[i] < pivot) {
             i++;
         }

         while (cakes[j] > pivot) {
             j--;
         }

         if (i <= j) {
             swap(cakes[i], cakes[j]);
             i++;
             j--;
         }
     }

     return i;
 }

 void Quick(vector<Tort>& cakes, int start, int end)
 {
     if (start >= end) {
         cout << "Less then 2 cakes in the vector.\n";
         return;
     }

     int index = divide(cakes, start, end);

     Quick(cakes, start, index - 1);
     Quick(cakes, index, end);
 }


 int read_cakes_from_file(vector<Tort>& cakes, string filename) {
     ifstream f(filename, ios::binary);
     if (!f.is_open()) {
         cout << "\nFile " << filename << " is not found!";
         return 0;
     }

     cakes.clear();
   

     f.seekg(0, 2);
     int n = (int)f.tellg() / sizeof(Tort);
     cout << "Number of cakes in the file = " << n << endl;
     f.seekg(0);
     Tort cake;
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         

         cake = Tort();
         f >> cake;

         cout << "i = " << (i+1)<<  cake;
         cakes.push_back(cake);
         
     }

     f.close();
     return cakes.size();
 }


 void displayAllTorts(string file_name) { 
     ifstream f(file_name, ios_base::binary);

     if (!f.is_open()) {
         cout << "Failed to open file " << file_name << endl;
         return;
     }

     f.seekg(0, 2);
     int n = (int)f.tellg() / sizeof(Tort);
     cout << "Number of objects in the file = " << n << endl;
     f.seekg(0);
     Tort cake;
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

         f >> cake;
         cout << cake;
     }

     f.close();
 }
```

I try to print all objects from binary files to concole using function `displayAllTorts()` with overloaded ifstream >> . But when the Tort instance cake is going to be deleted after reading I have a exception - memory access violation.

Comment: have you tried to diagnose where the problem occurs?

Comment: Binary `write` and `read` don't work for most class types, including `std::string`. The `string` hold a pointer to its data, and `write` only writes the pointer, not what is pointed to. When `read`ing it back in you just get a pointer that now points nowhere (access violation).

Comment: @user253751 yes , when for loop in displayAllTorts is comming to its end and destructor for the temporaty cake instance starts to work